# A nonlinear system of equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $d\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\delta:\mathbb{Z}_d\to\{0,1\}$ is defined by $\delta(n) = 1$ if $n=0$ and $\delta(n) = 0$ if $n\neq 0$.

**Question:** Does there exist a solution $x:\mathbb{Z}_d\to\mathbb{C}$ to the set of the equations $$\forall k,l\in\mathbb{Z}_d\hspace{10mm}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_d} x(n)\overline{x(n+k)}\ \overline{x(n+l)} x(n+k+l) = \frac{1}{d+1} (\delta(k) + \delta(l)) $$ for each $d\in\mathbb{N}$? Here $\overline{z}$ denotes the complex conjugate of $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: what happens for small $d$?

Comment: @mathworker21 There exist solutions for small $d$ merely found with the aid of minimization routines.